# 特定のクラスで定義された値を複数の別のクラスで参照し、書き換えたい

Tags: c#, unity3d

UnityのC#です。

```
public class A{
    public int[] tmp=new int[3]{1,2,3}
}
```

というクラスを

```
public class AddScript : MonoBehaviour {
    A a=new A();
    void Start(){
        a.tmp[0]++;
    }
```

という、GameObject（prefab化されており、複数回生成される)に付けられたScriptで呼ぶと、GameObjectが生成されるたびにtmpは初期化され、tmp[0]は1のままになります。
生成されるたびにtmp[0]の値が増えるようにするにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [Unity シーン間で変数を共有する方法](https://qiita.com/YuwUnknown/items/afdc9cd01de7c559ba60)、[遷移しても大丈夫！Unityの変数を異なるシーン間で共有する方法](https://freesworder.net/unity-variable-unchange/)

Comment: 解決しました！staticにして参照渡しすればよかったんですね！ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

staticにして参照渡しすれば解決しました。

---

<sup>この投稿は @エビうどん さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/53401/#comment55976_53401)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>